# Q: Single character to array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to come up with a code... let me explain...

1. I will use input to write a HEX number (A5B)
2. I will put the HEX number, each of its character to one location of array X (X[0]=A,X[1]=5,X[2]=B).
3. Then I want to use a SWITCH statement to find the coresponding BIT number for each of its HEX brother:

   ```
   switch(x[i])
   {
   case '0': cout << "0000"; break;
   case '1' :cout << "0001"; break;
   case '2': cout << "0010"; break;
   case '3': cout << "0011"; break;
   case '4': cout << "0100"; break;
   case '5': cout << "0101"; break;
   case '6': cout << "0110"; break;
   case '7': cout << "0111"; break;
   case '8': cout << "1000"; break;
   case '9': cout << "1001"; break;
   case 'A': cout << "1010"; break;
   case 'B': cout << "1011"; break;
   case 'C': cout << "1100"; break;
   case 'D': cout << "1101"; break;
   case 'E': cout << "1110"; break;
   case 'F': cout << "1111"; break;
   }
   ```
4. each of it i want to put into array Z, like for example (Z[0]=1010,Z[1]=0101,Z[2]=1011);
5. and then finaly print the array Z in reverse but to one single INT Bin.

Can you guys help me with that? I dont know how to do the input single character to Array, or the output of the array to single INT.
The output of the array to single bit could be something like this?

```
while (t!=0){
int Bin=Bin + Z[t];
Bin=Bin+g;
g*=1000;
t-=1;
 }
```

the "t" is the size of the array z from the step number 4. it will write the volume of that location to int Bin and then multiply the int Bin by 1 000, (for the shifting of the bin by four to the left) I dont know if you understand me 
English is not my native language but you get the idea from the code (that is magic because when someone in englis writes the code and sent it to Germany and they can't speak englis they can understand him)... okey but back to the topic... can you help me please? Thank you.

Comment: Please try to make as much of a [mcve] as you can, i.e. make a program which has the input value already available, I understand it to be a string stored in an array of char. (If getting that value in a suitable array of char is your problem, then rephrase your question heavily in order to make that clear and leave out all the rest, because in that case you are off-topic for asking more than one question at once.) This is of course your "1. and 2.". Your MCVE should also contain a loop, containing your "3.". The interesting/problematic part seems to be your "4. and 5.". But help needs an MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand your question but from what I could gather this appears to be what you want.

```
using namespace std:
int main(){

    string x;
    cin>>x;
    string z[x.size()]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i){
        switch(x[i]){
            case '0': z[i] = "0000";
                  break;
            case '1' :z[i] = "0001";break;
            case '2': z[i] = "0010";break;
            case '3': z[i] = "0011";break;
            case '4': z[i] = "0100";break;
            case '5': z[i] = "0101";break;
            case '6': z[i] = "0110";break;
            case '7': z[i] = "0111";break;
            case '8': z[i] = "1000";break;
            case '9': z[i] = "1001";break;
            case 'A': z[i] = "1010";break;
            case 'B': z[i] = "1011";break;
            case 'C': z[i] = "1100";break;
            case 'D': z[i] = "1101";break;
            case 'E': z[i] = "1110";break;
            case 'F': z[i] = "1111";break;
        }
    }
    string s(4*x.size(),'0');
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = x.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
        for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--){
            s[k] = z[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Also include iostream at the start.

Comment: Variable length arrays are non-standard and the code makes excessive allocations

Comment: I do know it can be done in a better way using vectors but this is what he asked in the question.

Comment: this is exactli what i was looking for! thank you very much, i know that the code could be writen in another, simplier way but i need to write it in this way for my profesor to understand it more logicly. Thank you very much for your time to code it!

Comment: just added a bottom line before 
`cout<<s<<endl`
I added 
`reverse(s.begin(),s.end());`
and included 
`#include <algorithm>`
because the output was in the oposite order.

Comment: You could have just changed the for loop for(int i = 0;i<x.size();i++) and for(int j = 0;j < 4;j++)